# How to change cell content on highlight

Tags: ios

In my *TableView* i load cells based on a xib file. The cell has a *imageView* in the background. How to change the image when user holds finger on a row? I dont meen *didSelectRowAtIndexPath*, cause it means the user tapped the row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implement the `- (void)setHighlighted:(BOOL)highlighted animated:(BOOL)animated` method on your cell subclass and change the image there based on the value of the `highlighted` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this help

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView shouldHighlightRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

     // update your image here

     return YES;
}
```